# How Make Links For Array Data In MySQL And PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i want make a different link for array data in mysql database.

for example i store data like below in my database:

data1,data2,data3 in one column

and i want fetch them like below by one query:

```
echo'
<a href="mydomain.php?'.$row[data1].'">data1</a>
<a href="mydomain.php?'.$row[data2].'">data2</a>
<a href="mydomain.php?'.$row[data3].'">data3</a>';
```

Comment: Storing `data1,data2,data3` in a single column should make you physically uncomfortable. This is a sign that your database is in desperate need of refactoring.

Comment: In any case, what is stopping you from retrieving `data1,data2,data3` from your one column and using it in your output?

Comment: i get some data from html form and this data maybe will one or several and i store them in one column in table like data1 or data1,data2 maybe i am wrong if you have database solution for store them please Guidance me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored as "data1,data2,data3" in a column named "column" of your table:

```php
$data = explode(",", $row["column"]);

echo '<a href="mydomain.php?'.$data[0].'">data1</a>';
```

But as said above, you should avoid storing multiple data in one column.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your database retrieving loop :

```
$data = explode(',',$row['COLOUMN_NAME']);
echo'
<a href="mydomain.php?'.$data[0].'">data1</a>
<a href="mydomain.php?'.$data[1].'">data2</a>
<a href="mydomain.php?'.$data[2].'">data3</a>';
```

Comment: thanks but one question. is this query correct for fetch data? SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%data1,data2%' ?

Comment: Yes , if they are in this order , i mean data1,data2 not data2,data1